# Question regarding metric spaces and open balls

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have just started with metric spaces and am reading Karl Stromberg's Introduction to Real Analysis. In one of the examples, the following is stated:

> If $X=\mathbb N\subset \mathbb R$ with the usual metric, then $B_1(2)$={$2$} and $B_{1.5}(2)$={$1,2,3$}

Can anyone explain what the above statement means? If a ball is centered at 2 with radius 1 how is the open ball a set containing only 2? And how is the open ball a set containing 1,2 and 3 only for the ball centered at 2 with a radius of 1.5?

Comment: Note $X=\Bbb N$. What integers are of distance less than $1$ from $2$?

Comment: Just 2? There are no other integers satisfying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point $x\in X$ is in $B_1(2)$ if and only if $|x-2|<1$. $X=\Bbb N$; what points of $\Bbb N$ satisfy $|x-2|<1$? Only the point $2$: If $x=0$, then $|x-2|=2\ge 1$; if $x=1$, then $|x-2|=1\ge 1$; and if $x\ge 3$, then $|x-2|=x-2\ge 1$.

Similarly, which natural numbers are less than $1.5$ units away from $2$? Only $1,2$, and $3$, which are $1,0$, and $1$ unit away from $2$, respectively. Every other natural number is at least $2$ is either $0$, which is $2$ units away from $2$, or greater than or equal to $4$ and hence at least $2$ units away from $2$.

It appears that you’re failing to take into account the fact that the space in question isn’t the whole real line: it’s just $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Oh ok I think I get it now. I was getting confused with the usual metric. If we were to say that $X=[0,1]$ with the rest of the conditions being the same, will the open ball be an empty set? Does the center of the open ball have to be included in $X$?

Comment: @Paradox101: In working with a space $X$, one normally considers only open balls centred at points of $X$. Occasionally, when $X$ is a subspace of some larger space $Y$, one might be interested in the intersection with $X$ of open balls centred at points of $Y$. In your example it is indeed true that $B_1(2)\cap[0,1]=\varnothing$, if $B_1(2)$ is the open ball in $\Bbb R$, but if I’m just working with the space $[0,1]$, there would normally be no reason to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with that the distance must be LESS THAN, never equal, to our given $\epsilon$, in your case a and 1½, if it's equal it's excluded. The rest is as Brian said